# Best way to find time segments in a time frame

Tags: swift, time

I am currently making an app where I have to retrieve allowances for certain hours worked.

For example, I work from 3:00 pm to 10:00 pm.
Between this time an allowance would be given between 8:00 pm - 10:00 pm 20% and from 10:00 pm to 11:00 pm 35%.

Until now I did not get much further than a rather complicated if construction.

```
if startUur <= 20 && eindUur >= 22 || 20..<22 ~= startUur || 20..<22 ~= eindUur || startUur > 20 && eindUur <= 22 && startMinuut > 0 || startUur < 20 {
//code to calculate allowance
}
```

I have been looking for a good  and better way to do this, but I cannot find it.

Is there a better way or am I bound to such a way with an if construction?

Comment: Erm what are the percents? Why is 10-11 given 35% and why is 8-10 given 20%?

Comment: The percentages are set for specific times. So from 20:00 to 22:00 is always 20% surcharge.

Comment: Could it be that it goes in between. So 19:00-23:00 could be a schedule where it touches 2 time frames?

Comment: Yes thats right 19:00 - 23:00 touches 2 time frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct TimeAndMoneyFrame {
    var timeHourStart:Int = 0
    var timeHourEnd:Int = 0
    var percentage: Double = 0
}

extension TimeAndMoneyFrame {
    func timeLength() -> Int {
        return timeHourEnd - timeHourStart
    }
}

let 2000to2200 = TimeAndMoneyFrame(timeHourStart = 20, timeHourEnd = 22, percentage = 0.2)
let 2200to2300 = TimeAndMoneyFrame(timeHourStart = 22, timeHourEnd = 23, percentage = 0.35)
let timeArray:[TimeAndMoneyFrame] = [2000to2200]

//Assuming 'startUur' means startingHour
//Assuming 'eindUur' means endingHour
let startUur:Int = someHour // You define some hour
let eindUure:Int = someHour // You define some hour
let hourlyRateOfPay: Double = somePay // You define some pay
var totalPay: Double = 0

for time in timeArray {
    let start = time.timeHourStart
    let end = time.timeHourEnd
    let percent = time.percentage

    //Encompasses entirely
    if(start > startUur && end < eindUur) {
        totalPay += (hourlyRateOfPay * (1 + percent) * time.timeLength())
    }

    //Only encompassed the left side - i.e., their time worked ends within this time frame
    else if(start > startUur) {
        let timeWithinThisFrame = eindUur - start
        totalPay += (hourlyRateOfPay * (1 + percent) * (timeWithinThisFrame/time.timeLength())
    }

    //Only encompassed right side - i.e., the beginning of the starts within this time frame
    else if(eindUur < end) {
        let timeWithinThisFrame = end - startUur
        totalPay += (hourlyRateOfPay * (1 + percent) * (timeWithinThisFrame/time.timeLength())
    }
}
```

So, we can break this problemn up into a couple problems.

1) Defining a struct/class that encompasses a time frame with an associated percentage

2) The algorithm necessary to calculate the total pay

I have a base assumption.

1) You say allowances - a person gets 35% if they work from 2200-2300 - I took this as a bonus so say 1.35% of the normal hourly rate. If this is not the case, the idea of consuming time frames one at a time would be the same. The only difference might be the totalPay calculation.

My algorithm goes through each time frame and determines if the current time intercepts any of the time frames. If it does, I calculate how much it intercepts and calculate the rate of pay.

Note: I coded all of this on SO - there might be some syntax issues.